# Impala not working on Hbase Table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, impala, nosql

Hi I have a Hbase table and I can query the same with Hive.
When I try to access the same from impala (either from HUE or shell) I get the following error :

```
Query: select * from clickview
ERROR: RuntimeException: couldn't retrieve HBase table (clickviewtab) info:
Enable/Disable failed
```

CDH version -  **cdh5.4.2**

Impala Version - **2.2.0**

Hbase version - **1.0.0-cdh5.4.2**

All Hbase , impala and hive are part of the CDH 5.4.2 release and been installed as package.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the capability for Impala to query HBase Tables in the Impala Configuration.

In Cloudera Magaer, go to the configuration options, search for hbase and then clic the radio button on HBase Service to enable it.